# SQL query in Node.js server looping

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to set up a server using Node.js.
For the database I am using Xampp.
I want to run the updateEngine() function when /update is provided.
Everything is working , except the code is looping and after a while I get an error.
(I used `node --max_old_space_size=2000000`)

- Output

  ```
  server is up!!  
  connected as id 38 
  into the query 
  connected as id 39
  into the query
  ```
- Error

  ```
   69777 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.8 (1456.7) -> 1398.8 (1456.7) MB, 1871.5 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
     71705 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.8 (1456.7) -> 1398.8 (1456.7) MB, 1928.0 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
     73346 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.8 (1456.7) -> 1398.8 (1456.7) MB, 1640.7 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
     75283 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.8 (1456.7) -> 1398.8 (1456.7) MB, 1937.4 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  ```

  ==== JS stack trace ========`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`
- Code

  ```
  http = require('http');
  var connect = require('connect');
  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var app = connect();


  app.use('/update',updateEngine);

  http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
  console.log("server is up!!");

  function updateEngine(request,response,done) {
      var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host: 'localhost',
          port: '3306',
          user: 'root',
          password: '',
          database: 'test'
      });
      connection.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) {
              console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
              return;
          }
          console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
      });

      connection.query('SELECT * FROM `testtable`' , function (error, results, fields) {
          console.log("into the query");
      });
      connection.end();
  }
  ```
- Xampp

  ```
  The MySQL server
  [mysqld]
  user = mysql
  port=3306
  socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
  skip-external-locking
  key_buffer = 16M
  max_allowed_packet = 500M
  table_open_cache = 64
  sort_buffer_size = 512K
  net_buffer_length = 8K
  read_buffer_size = 256K
  read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
  myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Send a response to your requests (even if it's just a simple 200 OK with no body). Right now it's never responding and so the client is probably timing out and automatically retrying the request.
2. Use a database connection pool that you create on startup instead of creating a new database connection for every single request. Using a connection pool is much more efficient since you are not creating and tearing down a connection every time (which adds overhead and latency to your requests).

Comment: I sent a simple 200 response but the error is still there...The path will be rarely used. Is this a node issue or mysql configuration ?

Comment: There is nothing else "wrong" with the code you've posted so far. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: testtable has 100.000 entries , is this a problem ? The response is presented in the browser before the query is finished

Comment: That *might* explain the OOM error, but it certainly does not explain the duplicate calls to `updateEngine()`.

Comment: I updated my question with sql details. can I avoid the error ? connection.end() stops the query ? It seems that in the activity monitor node is hitting 100% and then I get the error.